# Extra space in the beginning of the line in output

Tags: python

This is my very first question so don't be cruel, please :-)
(I tried to find something in the questions database, but wasn't sucseed).

Could you please advise me how can I remove extra spase in the beginning of the line in the output - temperature in Farenheit? If it is possible - the solution for beginner.

```
celsius = input('Enter Celsius temperature:\n')
fahrenheit = (float(celsius)*(9/5))+32
print('Fahrenheit temperature:\n',fahrenheit)

Enter Celsius temperature:                                            
100                                                                   
Fahrenheit temperature:                                               
 212.0
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `print('Fahrenheit temperature:', fahrenheit, sep='\n')`

Comment: Default separator when giving multiple strings to `print` is space char

Comment: Or just `print('Fahrenheit temperature:')` and `print(fahrenheit)` or `print(f'Fahrenheit temperature:\n{fahrenheit}')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without a newline or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might set `sep` (separator) to empty `str`, as by default it is space, that is replace

```
print('Fahrenheit temperature:\n',fahrenheit)
```

using

```
print('Fahrenheit temperature:\n',fahrenheit,sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function puts a space separator in the output by default. You could either use two print statements to put the output on two separate lines, or provide an override value to remove the space.

```
print('Fahrenheit temperature:', fahrenheit, sep='\n')
```